# Как настроить 301 редирект в .htaccess?

Tags: .htaccess, apache

Как правильно написать редирект:

```
https://example.com/product/productname1
```

на

```
https://example.com/productname1
```

?

Comment: А почему не сразу через mod_rewrite, зачем доводить до ошибки 301?

Comment: @ГерманБорисов 301 - это не ошибка, это код ответа который сообщит поисковым системам, что страница перемещена навсегда. Делается, чтобы не потерять трафик и позиции в поисковике.

Comment: https://devaka.ru/articles/redirect-301 - первый же результат в google по заголовку вашего вопроса.

Comment: Герман Борисов, Ваша теория имеет смысл, но у меня в данный момент в сео-тз написано поставить редиректы на несколько страниц